Cannot create extension in postgres 14
running postgres 14 on REHL 8
I installed v14.

(I previously had v10 on this server and had no issues. Not sure what is different)
I cannot create an extension --  what am I missing????
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
returns:  ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/uuid-ossp": No such file or directory 


select from pg_extension;
returns nothing   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<---- why?????

[postgres@AFEBSPGSQLD01 data.14]$ /usr/pgsql-14/bin/pg_config --libdir
/usr/pgsql-14/lib
[postgres@AFEBSPGSQLD01 data.14]$ /usr/pgsql-14/bin/pg_config --sharedir
/usr/pgsql-14/share


extension definitions are in  /usr/pgsql-14/share/extension

I tried copying uuid-ossp into /usr/pgsql-14/lib/extension and nothing changed.
Thanks,
Copied uuid-ossp into dirlib/extension


To make use of the common extensions to PostgreSQL you have to install the postgres-contrib module for version 14. So: postgresql14-contrib for RHEL (I believe). uuid-ossp is not part of the core distribution for postgres, so you have install it separately when using a package manager. eg.
dnf install postgresql14-contrib

Relevant documentation:

If you are using a pre-packaged version of PostgreSQL, these components are typically made available as a separate subpackage, such as postgresql-contrib.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib.html

Thank you very much!  I had used "yum install postgresql-contrib" which is clearly (now) wrong.

If the above answer resolved your issue, or lead you to the solution, then kindly accept it. This aids future users having the same or similar issue and removes it from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave a successfully answered question as unanswered.
